# Get quote_item data using quote id and product id filter in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have to get the data from quote_item table using quote id and product id filter in Magento 2.

I was doing like this but it's not the good way

```
$connection->select()
    ->from(
        ['ce' => 'quote_item'],
        ['length']
    )->where('ce.quote_id IN (?) ',$quoteId)
    ->where('ce.product_id IN (?) ',$product_id);
```

Comment: We need to think about the simple way in this case. Each quote item has a unique product id. So, in this case, we just need to load the quote item by quote id. And, need to get the product id for comparison. `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface -> get($id);
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface -> getProductId();`

Comment: @Amrit Pal Singh why not use `\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ItemFactory` to filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\CollectionFactory as   QuoteFactory;

public function __construct(
    QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
) {
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;

}
 $this->quoteFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('quote_id',$quoteId)->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$productId);
```

Comment: You can also get quote data by Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository::get(quote_id)