# Magento 2- get cart items for a given product ID

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart

In Magento 1 it's done like this

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();

$cartItems = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
```

Is it possible in Magento 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession) 
 {
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
}

    $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
    $cartItems = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
```

Comment: but i have passed only product id not full product

Comment: @RahulVaghela Oh i see!!!
Please check if below link can help to you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227462/get-quote-item-data-using-quote-id-and-product-id-filter-in-magento-2?rq=1

Comment: @RutveeSojitra, $cartItems didn't return anything to me, I am passing product Object

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code for it

```
    <?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
  protected $_productloader; 
  protected $_checkoutSession; 
  public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession

    ) {

        $this->_productloader = $_productloader;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }
    public function getItemById()
    {
        $product=$this->_productloader->create()->load($id);
        $quote = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
        $cartItems = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
    }

}
```

Or you can use Below code

```
$om =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$quote = $om->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart')->getQuote();
$product = $om->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
$item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same in Magento 2.

You can inject Quote Session (`\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session`) and use getItemByProduct function.

Example:
Inject Quote Session

```
/**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ) {   
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }
```

And use getItemByProduct function

```
$this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($product);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code :

```
protected $_productFactory;
protected $checkoutSession;

public function __construct(
    ..........
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productFactory,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    ..........
) 
{
    ..........
    $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    $this->_productFactory = $_productFactory;
    ..........
}

public function execute()
{
    $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
    $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($product_id);
    $_item = $quote->getItemByProduct($product);
}
```

**Note : Do not use ObjectManager Directly.**