# Magento2: I want to get customer cart item collection without customer login

Tags: magento2, frontend, quoteitem, cart-items

How to get customer cart item collection without customer login?

I want to also get cart item through item id.

**Got the null value**

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module_name\Block\Index;

class Approveitem extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    protected $_coreRegistry;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ItemFactory $quoteItemFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item $itemResourceModel
    )
    {
       $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
       $this->quoteItemFactory = $quoteItemFactory;
       $this->itemResourceModel = $itemResourceModel;
       parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCartDetails(){
        $itemId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('itemId');

        $quoteItem = $this->quoteItemFactory->create();
        $item = $this->itemResourceModel->load($quoteItem, $itemId);

        return $item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to using this answer =>https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/241844/51810

Comment: Inform me is it working for you or not.

Comment: It is not working. Got the null value. Because I am not login to the customer. I want to get the cart item data collection form database without customer login.

Comment: Any other method so we can get the item collection without customer login not using session. @RohanHapani

Comment: Yes. I update answer within few minute.

Comment: You want to get all product collection which is in cart by quote id. right?

Comment: No, I want to get cart item using item id. @RohanHapani

Comment: Please check my post. I have updated my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85780/discussion-between-masud-shaikh-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: Check my answer. I tested it and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this below code :

```
protected $cart;
protected $itemResourceModel;
protected $quoteRepository;
public function __construct(
    .......
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item $itemResourceModel,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $quoteRepository
    .......
) {
    .......
    $this->cart = $cart;
    $this->itemResourceModel = $itemResourceModel;
    $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    .......
}
=============================

$itemsCollection = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemsCollection();
$cartID = $this->cart->getQuote()->getId();
foreach ($itemsCollection as $item) {
    $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartID);
    $quoteItem = $quote->getItemById($item->getItemId());
}
```

Comment: It is not working. Got the null value in item collection.

Comment: I tested it and it's working properly without customer login. Can you please check ?I think something is not working. can you please post your whole code?

Comment: The code is working when I add the item to the cart without customer login.

Comment: My senario is already i have item id. I want to get the cart data using my item id

Comment: Please check my post. I have already updated my code. I have got the item id from using the coreRegistry method.

Comment: echo $itemId  and check it. Did you get proper?

Comment: Yes, I got the item_id = 714 also I checked-in database is there.

Comment: That item id's product in cart or already order placed?

Comment: quote id is different and the item is different. So I want to get cart item using item id not using quote id.

Comment: Yes, Already product added in the cart through the customer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85781/discussion-between-masud-shaikh-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: Any idea how to get customer cart item collection without customer login?